# How to convert a data type into a MonadState

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, monads

I have these types:

```
data Tree a = Branch (Tree a) a (Tree a) | Leaf
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

newtype State' s a = State' { runState' :: (s, Counts) -> (a, s, Counts) }
```

With these instances:

```
instance Monad (State' s)
instance MonadState (State' s) s
```

And I need to make a function

```
label :: MonadState m Int => Tree a -> m (Tree (Int, a))
```

But I don't know how I can convert a tree into a `State'`.

Comment: What does the `label` function actually need to do?  I can define it as `label = undefined` and it'll compile, but that doesn't mean it's the behavior you want.

Comment: It has to label a tree with integers increasingly, using a depth-first in-order traversal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert the `Tree` to your stateful value, you need to use the stateful value of `Int` at each stage of the labeling process.  For that, you'll probably benefit from something like

```
getLabelAndIncr :: MonadState m Int => m Int
getLabelAndIncr = do
    current <- get
    put $ current + 1
    return current
```

Then in your `label` function you can do something like

```
label :: MonadState m Int => Tree a -> m (Tree (Int, a))
label Leaf = return Leaf
label (Branch left node right) = do
    l <- getLabelAndIncr
    let newNode = (l, node)
    newLeft <- ???
    newRight <- ???
    return $ Branch newLeft newNode newRight
```

You'll have to figure out what goes in the `???`, I'm not going to solve all of this one for you, but it should be a fairly straightforward exercise.  What is happening here is that `getLabelAndIncr` gets the current label value to use, then stores that value incremented in the state.  Then a new node value is constructed that is tagged with that label, the left and right branches get their tags, and a new tree is returned that now has labels.  The type of the state stays the same each time, that's fixed by `MonadState m Int`, which says that `m` is a stateful monad that *always* has a state value that is an `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert the `Tree` into a state, the `m (Tree (Int, a))` part of the type signature just means that the result will be a `Tree` containing tupels of `Int`s and `a`s, which itself is inside a state monad. It doesn't even have to be the `State'` monad.